# LaTeX, conceal and weird coloring

Tags: vim, latex

I have vim, and like the Tex conceal option. Specifically, if I have `let g:tex_conceal="sabgm"` in my `~/.vimrc`, whenever I type `$\beta$`, I see β. But, after switching color themes, I get some weird output:

[image: bad-highlighting]

Answer (score 4):

As found [here](https://b4winckler.wordpress.com/2010/08/07/using-the-conceal-vim-feature-with-latex/), you have to have    `hi Conceal guibg=White guifg=Black` (or similar) in your `~/.vimrc`.

[image: good-highlighting]

*edit 2020-07-19* I've since written a blog post titled "[Vim syntax highlighting for Markdown, Liquid and MathJax](https://stsievert.com/blog/2016/01/06/vim-jekyll-mathjax/)." It walks through a method to provide Latex and Liquid highlighting for Jekyll. It's pretty easy to adapt for only Latex:

```
# eg inside .vimrc
function! MathHighlight()
    "" Define certain regions
    " Block math. Look for "$$[anything]$$"
    syn region math start=/\$\$/ end=/\$\$/
    " inline math. Look for "$[not $][anything]$"
    syn match math_block '\$[^$].\{-}\$'

    "" Actually highlight those regions.
    hi link math Statement
    hi link liquid Statement
    hi link highlight_block Function
    hi link math_block Function
endfunction

" Call everytime we open a Markdown file
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile,BufEnter *.md,*.markdown call MathHighlight()
```

Comment: The link is dead, could you please tell me what worked for you? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Edited. Now, I provide the method I use.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what worked for me.
Add `hi clear Conceal` at the bottom of your `.vimrc`.